# Scalable django app, should message queue be located on load balancer or app server?

Tags: django, nginx, rabbitmq, celery, gunicorn

I've just architected my first scalable backend for a django app, however I put the message queue service (RabbitMQ) on the load balancer machine. I was able to siege some of my API routes with up to 500 concurrent users without a serious time deficit but I'm wondering if I'd have any better performance by putting the MQ service somewhere else.

My setup right now:

app requests > load balancer (nginx, rabbitmq) > workers, 2 in use (gunicorn/celery) > db (postgres)

So I have currently 4 AWS EC2 instances (all m3.medium) connected up in a VPC doing all this for me. It wouldn't make much sense to do rabbit on the worker nodes so I'm just trying to get an idea of what people do.

I'm also curious about how to best configure gunicorn but from my searching it doesn't seem like there's a whole lot to mess with other than number/type of actual workers. Which for my AWS EC2 instance (m3.medium) is only 3/synchronous (got worse performance using async workers).

Answer (score 0):

the setup of your servers and applications depends on the load and capacity of your server.

Where are using load balancer > Applications/Workers server > DB server
we have multiple different servers where rabbitmq, redis, etc are running on.

If your servers load balancer server can handle rabbitmq next to it, I see no reason to change this.
It's really difficult to tell you what the 'best' way is.

And I think if your current solution runs without any problems I would keep that until you are about to run into problems (keep a close eye on your logs, etc) and make your decision based on that information.